# TYPO3 Direct Mail List-Unsubscribe header

Tags: typo3

How can I add the List-Unsubscribe header to direct_mail. Does anyone have an example?
As far as I could see there is a hook for doing this: https://github.com/kartolo/direct_mail/pull/3 - but I did not find an example how I could implement this hook.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you

Christian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create an user class. Here an little example:

```
<?php
  namespace Vendor\Extension\Hooks;

  class DirectMail
  {

    /**
     * @param array $params
     * @param object $parentObject
     */
    public function header($params, $parentObject) {
      # get the userdata
      $row = $params['row'];
      /** @var \Swift_Mime_HeaderSet $header */
      $header = $params['header'];

      $header->addTextHeader('List-Unsubscribe', '<LINK_TO_UNSUBSCRIPE>');
    }

  }
```

Now you have to define the hook in your own extension `ext_localconf.php`:

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['ext/direct_mail']['res/scripts/class.dmailer.php']['mailHeadersHook'][] = 'Vendor\Extension\Hooks\DirectMail->header';
```

Comment: Would be great to see a working example how to add headers. E.g. List-Unsubscribe-Header. I [https://s17.directupload.net/images/190918/dmwdtpzy.png](debugged the params object) but did not know how to add a new header.

Comment: I edited the example with an simple TextHeader for "List-Unsubscribe" header @ntiedt